# Need angularJS dropdown width to fill whole screen from far left to far right.

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an anglarJS project that has a horizontal navigation bar. Each element in the navigation bar is a category and uses an angularJS dropdown directive to show the subcategories for that category.

I would like the drop down to fill the whole screen from left to right.  Currently the drop down determines it's width from the css "min-width" property.  This does not solve my desire for the drop down menu to fill the whole screen I have seen some websites do this, and was wondering if there is a way to force my dropdown to fill the whole screen from left to right.

[image]

Here is the html for the page/drop down including the css that specifies the dropdown width.

[image]

Here is a picture of the dropdown again. I added blue arrows to indicate what I mean when I want the drop down to fill the whole screen.

[image]

The pictures are pretty high resolution and show you all the details. The page is rather complex to try and replicated in a plunker.

The whole thing needs to be responsive as well, and is based off of Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS Bootstrap.

Thanks for any help you can give!

David

Comment: I've thought that I might be able to solve the problem with an angularJS Bootstrap modal directive, but that would take a lot more time to set up, and if there is an easy CSS solution for this, then I would prefer to go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem.

I created a button group that floats left that is on the same row as the button group in the center.  The button group that floats left only contains one button, and that button has it's visibility set to hidden.
You have the dropdown attached to this button, rather than the ones in the center, since the dropdown won't start any farther left than the beginning of the button it is attached to.

```
<div class="pull-left">
        <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="isOpen">
            <button type="button" style="visibility: hidden" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle filter-criteria-variety-category-name" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="dropdown-menu top-level-category-drop-down-standard" ng-style="{{windowWidth}}" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" >
                <div ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"  ng-mouseleave="close()" ng-mouseenter="keepOpen()">
                    <div ng-if="currentCategory != undefined">
                        <horizontal-menu-inner close-drop-down-menu=$parent.closeDropDownMenu top-level-category=$parent.currentCategory></horizontal-menu-inner>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And for the centered button group that contains your categories you want to trigger the dropdown you pass the 'ioOpen' variable into the centered button directive as an attribute.

```
<div class="text-center">
        <div  class="btn-group">
            <div class="horizontal-top-level-category" ng-repeat="topLevelCategory in categoryNavigationGraph">
                <horizontal-top-level-category is-open=$parent.isOpen current-category-id=$parent.currentCategoryId top-level-category=topLevelCategory></horizontal-top-level-category>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You then have that directive set up to close or open the drop down depending on whether the mouse enters or leaves the button in that directive

```
<button ng-mousemove="activeMenuItemm()" ng-mouseleave="close($event)" ng-mouseenter="open()" type="button"  ng-class="{'filter-criteria-variety-category-name-hover': filterCriteriaCategoryActive}"   class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle filter-criteria-variety-category-name" ng-disabled="disabled">
{{topLevelCategory.text}}
```

The tricky part is not having the dropdown close when you hover down from the centered button onto the dropdown

I did this by figuring out if the mouse was leaving from "down", which should not close the dropdown, or other, which should from the last position, which was calculated In the centered button directive link function:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
        init();
        scopeLevelFunctions();
        function init(){
             calculateBoundry();
        }
        function scopeLevelFunctions(){
            scope.calculateElementBoundry = function(){
                calculateBoundry();
            }
        }
        function calculateBoundry(){
            var boundry =  element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            scope.boundry = boundry;
            scope.topBoundry = boundry.top;
            scope.bottomBoundry = boundry.bottom;
            scope.leftBoundry = boundry.left;
            scope.rightBoundry = boundry.right;
        }

    },
```

The open function triggered by mouseenter sets the boundry, which the close calculates from that value to see if this is a mouseleave that is leaving down

```
$scope.open = function(){
$scope.calculateElementBoundry();
$scope.currentCategoryId = $scope.topLevelCategory.categoryId;
$scope.filterCriteriaCategoryActive = true;
$scope.timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
    $scope.isOpen = true;
}, 150);
```

};

```
$scope.close = function($event){
$scope.lastPosition = {
    x : $event.clientX,
    y : $event.clientY
};
var deltaX = $scope.lastPosition.x - $event.clientX,
    deltaY = $scope.lastPosition.y - $event.clientY;
if($event.clientY >= ($scope.bottomBoundry - 8))
    $scope.direction = "bottom";
else
    $scope.direction = "other";
if($scope.direction != "bottom"){
    if($scope.timeoutPromise != undefined)
        $timeout.cancel(this.timeoutPromise);
    $scope.isOpen = false;
    $scope.filterCriteriaCategoryActive = false;
}
else{
    if($scope.isOpen == false && $scope.timeoutPromise != undefined){
        $timeout.cancel(this.timeoutPromise);
        $scope.filterCriteriaCategoryActive = false;
    }
}
```

I put the timeout in there so that if the user is just scrolling to bottom of the screen the drop down does not just appear.  I cancel the timeout if they mouseleave and the drop down is not open.

The dropdown gets different data in it because the centered category directive has an attribute "categoryId" that is shared with the directive that the dropdown is located in.  As that categoryId is changed that directive determines what that new categories submenu should be and feeds that into the dropdown.

I know how wide the dropdown should be because in the directive that contains the dropdown/invisible button I calculated the window width:

```
var width = $window.innerWidth;
            $scope.windowWidth = "{'min-width':" + width + "}";
```

and on the dropdown I use ng-style to set this width

```
ng-style="{{windowWidth}}"
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If there is a different way for me to have my dropdown go full screen width without having to use $window.innerWidth , I would love to hear about it, as I tried that route and failed.